# MVCContrib input builder vs MVC 2 editor templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, mvccontrib, input-builders

Is there any comparison? Pros and cons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC 2 editor template is an evolution of MVCContrib input builder.

It's true that is missing a few things, like [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532306/mvccontrib-input-builder-vs-mvc-2-editor-templates/2532507#2532507) said, but It's a fact that it's has a stronger architecture.

Pros:

1. Have a special folder `EditorTemplates` under the shared folder AND under the view! (area supported too). In the older MVCContrib input builder you must put the templates in the a shared folder. In order to use it with a special folder you must add a new view engine that will look on this folder.

Cons:

None.

Answer (score 2):

Pros of input builders: they can recognize attributes on the model such as `MaximumStringLength` and set the `maxlength` html attribute. They also can recognize the presence of the `Required` attribute and put the `required` class on the element.

Pros of editor templates: support of [incremental sequencing](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/02/).

Comment: +1 for the incremental sequencing link, been hand rolling that for awhile now. This helps.